# Mongodb conditional find

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'am posting 3 data to my routes.js and i want if this 3 data not null or empty than query should be like that :

```
db.collection.find({posteddata1:req.body....,posteddate2:req.body....,posteddata3:req.body...})
```

If one data is null or emty than my query:

```
db.collection.find({posteddate2:req.body....,posteddata3:req.body...})
```

If all data is null or emtpty than my query shold be:

```
db.collection.find({});
```

I dont want to use if else statement. Is there easy way to do that.

Comment: I think you cloud only modifty the where object, inited with {}, and if posteddata1 not empty, set where.posteddata1, .....finally db.collection.find(where);

Comment: I was also looking for the 'right' solution for the same usecase but the accepted answer below is not optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cant your case be made like  :

```
if(db.collection.find({a:1,b:2,c:3}).count() > 0) {

    //do db.collection.find({a:1,b:2,c:3});

} else if(db.collection.find({b:2,c:3}).count() > 0) {

    //do db.collection.find({b:2,c:3});

} else {

    //do db.collection.find({});

}
```